# Process.start on network drive, ask for authentication

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, file-sharing, windows-networking, shared-resource

Considering this code:

```
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\\some_network_host\path";
    process.Start();
```

I would like to connect to a shared resource and open the path in `Explorer.exe`, however, the user might not be authenticated yet. If the user is not authenticated, I would like to open a Windows authentication popup just like the one I see when I run `\\some_network_host\path`, however, my actual code just opens "**My Document**" instead (if the user is not already authenticated). If the user is already authenticated, it opens the explorer.exe window showing the shared resource.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works fine for me

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\existing_network_host\path";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true; 
process.Start();
```

The keey difference is true value for StartupInfo.ErrorDialog